# Converting multiple PDF files into txt in Python?

Tags: python, pypdf, pdftotext

```
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

for filename in os.listdir("C:/117"):
    path = os.path.join("C:/117/", filename)
    print(path)
    with open('file.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        for page_num in range(PdfFileReader(path).numPages):
            print('Page: {0}'.format(page_num))
            pageObj = PdfFileReader(path).getPage(page_num)
            
            try:
                txt = pageObj.extractText()
            except:
                pass
            else:
                file.write('Page{0}\n'.format(page_num+1))
                file.write(txt)
        file.close()
```

I am converting hundreds of pdf files into txt. However, with this code, all the PDFs are merged into a single txt file. Is there a way to create separate txt file for each PDF I convert? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```py
from pathlib import Path

from pypdf import PdfReader


def convert_pdf_to_text(path: Path) -> str:
    text = ""
    for page in PdfReader(path).pages:
        text += page.extract_text() + "\n"
    return text


for path in Path("Documents").glob("**/*.pdf"):
    text = convert_pdf_to_text(path)

    txt_path = path.parent / (".".join(path.name.split(".")[:-1]) + ".txt")
    if txt_path.exists():
        print(f"Skip {txt_path} as it already exists")
        continue
    with open(txt_path, "wt") as fp:
        fp.write(text)
```